# bash input/output redirect doesn't work

Tags: bash, cut, io-redirection

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with the following bash code

```
for f in $FILES
do
  cut -d, f1-7 < $f > $f.tmp
done
```

When I run in the loop

```
echo "cut -d, f1-7 < $f > $f.tmp"
```

I get the right command output and when I run that command by itself, it works perfectly. But when I run it in the bash loop, it doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
cut: you must specify a list of bytes, characters, or fields
Try `cut --help' for more information.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: i think you might have forgotten "-" before "f1-7", and you might have to escape the comma

Comment: @Qnan In fact,that's the answer!

Comment: Yea, I'm an idiot, I just wasted half an hour cuz of that dash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you miss a minus sign in your cut command:

```
cut -d, -f1-7 < $f > $f.tmp
```